# Yii, jQuery: can I make jQuery code generated by ajaxLink() load before other scripts?

Tags: jquery, yii, jquery-trigger

I'm making tabbed content in Yii manually, so the content would load data from AJAX. I'm using `ajaxLink()` and it works fine. The selected tab ID is stored in session so when I reload the page, the same tab is selected again. The problem is, the content will load only when I press a tab(link), instead of loading automatically. So I figured out I could use `jQuery.trigger()` function to simulate a click on page load. But it doesn't work, probably because Yii generates the script and places it at the end of the page, so the `.trigger("click")` function doesn't do anything - it can't access the AJAX code because it isn't generated yet.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I know this is a bad solution but I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shold add script which triggered event after the DOM is ready:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
     'linkText', 
     'url', 
     array('update'=>'#conteinerId'),
     array('class'=>'activeTabLink')
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript( 
   'ajaxTabLinkScript', 
   '$(function(){ $(".activeTab").click()})', 
   CClientScript::POS_LOAD 
);
```

Pay attention to `CClientScript::POS_LOAD` parameter. Thanks to him, this function is performed after to link is added the update event.